# How to store Multiple value in a variable in Sql Server

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following TSQL Statement:

```
declare @id1 int
set  @id1 = (select o.OrderId from [Order] o where o.M_Order_Id=@id)      

set @Message =  select om.Modifier_Id 
                from [Order] o , Order_Modifiers om
                where om.Order_Id=o.OrderId and om.Order_Id = @id1
```

I have to fetch the data according to "OrderId". which is store in a varibale "@Id1", Here variable @id1 will Return more than 1 value. this code not able to read more than one value, How to read this value one by one via loop etc. i want to put this value in blow query for fetch the data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a cursor in order to achieve this.

```
    create procedure test(@id int)
    declare @message_id     nvarchar(4000),
            @id             int,
            @id1            int


        DECLARE @TEMP_table TABLE
        (   id1 int ) 
        INSERT INTO @TEMP_table select o.OrderId from dbo.[Order] o where o.M_Order_Id=@id

        declare @temp_table2 table
        ( id int,message_id int)

        declare c1 cursor for 

                select distinct id1 from @temp_table

        open c1

        fetch next from c1 into @id1

        while @@fetch_status=0
        begin
            insert into @temp_table2    
                select o.order_id,om.Modifier_Id 
                    from [Order] o , Order_Modifiers om
                    where om.Order_Id=o.OrderId and om.Order_Id = @id1
        end

        close c1
        deallocate c1

    select * from @temp_table2
```

Comment: Hii mdj3884 Thanks 4 reply..i changed my code but i got error 
"The multi-part identifier "o.M_order_id" could not be bound." because @TEMP_table x having more than 1 value.how to read one bye one.

Comment: Do you want this script to return the message id for each and every id1 or in the form of a table like id1,message_id?

Comment: Thanks @mdj3884 I changed the stored procedure and it solved my issue.. Thakns for your help!!!